# Creating svn user

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I created svn user adding username to authz and passwd  and I commited my project from eclipse to repo. At history there is no username.I want to commit with my user account . What I to miss ?

Answer (score 0):

You **must** have commits enabled *only for authenticated users*. This is task of configuring server (svnserve or Apache)

Comment: Thanks for response , how will I configure this , can you give some details ?

Comment: I added to authz  [general]
 anon-access = none
 auth-access = read
 password-db = passwd , it solved.